# Include file from another domain sam server - 'failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/......'

Tags: php, centos, include, open-basedir

I have build a custom CMS which is stored on a domain and the files are included on other website behind different domains on the same VPS. This way I can update my CMS without having to change every site.

I'm running CentOS7.2 with Plesk 12.5.3
I keep getting the error

> 'failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/......'
>   'Fatal error: Class 'Language' not found in /var/www/vhosts/....'

What I did so far?

- open_basedir changed to none in site config and also in the ini file
- turned off selling
- disabled plesk firewall
- chmod directory/files to 755 or 777

I tested everything in the suggest duplicate url but it's still not working! Can't seem to get it working without any errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: I did a test with 
[code]<?php
system("namei -l /var/www/vhosts/enz");
?>[/code]

I can reach the other domain but no directories within the other domain. Than I get the error 'no such file or directory'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of the `allow_url_fopen` php.ini setting:

```
var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));
```

It's probably `false`. You'll need to either set it to `true` or ask your web hosting company to do so.

You could try

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);
```

If the value is set to `true` or `On`, could you eanble error reporting?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

It can also be usefull to check the `/var/log/httpd` error log corresponding to your website.

Comment: I checked the ini file, the allow_url_fopen was already set to 'on'

Comment: Failed opening '/var/www/vhosts/x.nl/develop.x.nl/cockpit/include/language.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/lib/php/session')

Comment: Has apache got acess to that file?

Comment: How can I check if apache has access to that file?

Comment: When you use the `ls -lh` command in the directory, it shows the `groups` and `permissions`.

Comment: The user is my the ftp user and the group is psacln, is that what you mean?

Comment: I solved the issue by a chmod of the subdomain to 751